# launch YouTube from the command line

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

is there a way to launch YouTube from the command line? I'd like to set a keyboard shortcut.

thanks so much! Origen

Comment: yes [see here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/160221/345853) I use youtube-dl in terminal for downloading videos from youtube and other sources and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

You can install [Freetube](https://freetubeapp.io/#download), a privacy friendly youtube client, and launch it with the command `freetube`.

Alternatively, you can open YouTube with Firefox, with the command

```
firefox https://youtube.com
```

For assigning keyboard shortcuts to a command, see [this webpage](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html).

Comment: Terrific - that's what I was looking for! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what *exactly* you want, it can be as simple as

```
xdg-open https://www.youtube.com
```

which will start your default web browser with that URL; or open a new tab in a browser instance that is already open.

Comment: The user wants to open Youtube from a shortcut key, so this is definitely the good and best answer.

Comment: Terrific - that's what I was looking for! Thanks so much!

Comment: Then please don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer. ;-)